# Calculate a count in Power BI considering two date columns

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with 3 columns, Case ID, Createdon, modifiedon. I want to calculate a weekly count of Cases by using modifiedon but cases shouldn't have been created in the same week. I can easily do this for any single data point, but how do I achieve this for a weekly trend.

Just to elaborate on the problem. If you see the image below I have casenumber, createdon, and modifiedon. Right now I've selected 2nd July on the bar graph. I want it to give me a count of cases where modified on is the week bw 2nd & 9th and createdon shouldn't be between the same time period, all the cases where created on is bw 2nd & 9th should be removed. I can create a measure and ask it to exclude the current week but it'll just be for a single point in time. I want to achieve whenever I click on any particular week on the bar graph, it shows the cases modified in that week, excluding the cases which were also created in the same week.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating a new week number column and filtering out based on it.